# Error, String not recognized as valid DateTime when trying to ParseExact time string

Tags: c#, datetime

The following fails after executing the highlighted line.

[image]

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

It's happening all the sudden, worked when it was 12PM or so... ? Now its 4:54PM and no go. What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `hh:mm:ss tt` as the format string - `HH` is for the 24-hour clock, at which point you're saying it's 4AM... but with PM as the AM/PM signifier.

Basically, use `hh` with `tt`, or `HH` on its own.

Using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), you'd use:

```
private static readonly LocalTimePattern TimePattern = 
    LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("hh:mm:ss tt");
// TODO: Check this is what you want! We can't tell from your example.
private static readonly LocalDatePattern DatePattern =
    LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dd/MM/yyyy");
private static readonly LocalDateTimePattern DateTimePattern =
    LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

public static string GetMergedDateTime(string dateText, string timeText)
{
    // The Value property throws an exception if parsing failed. You can
    // check that with the Success property first though.
    LocalDate date = DatePattern.Parse(dateText).Value;
    LocalTime time = TimePattern.Parse(timeText).Value;
    LocalDateTime dateTime = date + time;
    return DateTimePattern.Format(dateTime);
}
```

Note that it might be cleaner to return the `LocalDateTime` - do as much of your work as possible in the "natural" representation, only using strings when you really have to.

Comment: Thanks, is there a nicer way to write that piece of code? Instead of creating two `DateTime` and then concatenating them?

Comment: @Dayan: Well I'd personally use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) and parse a `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` then combining the two... but I'm biased :)

Comment: I may just give that a shot, would you mind providing a quick example using Noda time? Honestly, when i began the project i researched Noda Time but seemed a bit overkill since this is pretty much all DateTime work i'm doing ;P

Comment: @Dayan: I've provided an example. As you say, if this is all you're doing, it may be overkill - but worth knowing for the future :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, Keep rocking!